# Apart from Objective-C, which languages can I use when developing for Mac OS and iOS?

Tags: ios

I want to start developing for Mac and iPhone. I'm familiar with Objective-C a little and found it pretty complicated. Besides, I'm not sure that it would be worthwhile to learn it.

So it is possible to develop for Mac/iOS without knowing Objective-C, what programming languages do I have to use then? C++, C?

I like Scala, Java, by the way.

Comment: You can develop for Mac in nearly whatever language you want. It's getting more complicated when looking at iOS...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use c and c++ but you can't make any application without using objective - c. Since you need to use native app controllers and libraries.

Also in starting you find it difficult to learn obj-c because of it's syntaxes but after using them you are going to love it. So don't be scared and learn obj-c.

You can use some frameworks (e.g aapcelerator, phone gap)
but they are unable to give result like native app.

Answer (score 1):

Why not? !!

But for **iOS Native Development**, you should learn objective C.
And if you want to develop using any other languages, you should use some other frameworks.

Haven't you heard about [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/), [jqueryMobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) ,[monotouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch) etc?

Answer (score 1):

There are many frameworks you can use, like Mono where you can use C# (http://xamarin.com/monotouch) or some frameworks with HTML5 (see [Creating native iOS/Android apps from HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268900/creating-native-ios-android-apps-from-html5))

But at the end basic understanding of objective-c and it's architecture will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the hang of it `Objective-c` is actually quite fun.

Download some [iOS samples](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code) and step through the code, that will greatly help you.

Or just create an empty project like a "Master/Detail" tableview app and see how it works.